# I need to migrate my code from JBoss AS 4.0.2 GA to JBoss EAP 4.2.0 CP1

Tags: jboss, migration

There is a need for me to migrate my code from JBoss AS 4.0.2 GA to JBoss EAP 4.2.0 CP1.
I have less knowledge about JBoss EAP.

Kindly guide me through the stpes briefly.

Guidance will be greatly helpful..

Comment: EAP is just the officially supported snapshot of the community release. In practice, EAP 4.2 is no different from JBoss AS 4.2

Comment: Hi Skaffman,
           Thanx for your reply... but can u elaborate your point... actually this action of migration have been recommended by the Security auditing party which u can find also in the forward threads:
http://www.nessus.org/u?7864017e
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=585899
https://www.redhat.com/security/data/cve/CVE-2010-1428.html
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=457757


Kindly provide more details of the contrast bw these two servers after going through the above threads..
your help is highly appreciated....

Comment: @skaffman, that's not right. It's not a snapshot. CP's not even more. They contain a plethora of bug fixes which **are not backported to the community releases** of the same originating code base. And also performance fixes and sometimes minor features.

Answer (score 0):

While JBoss EAP is not just a snapshot of a community version - you simply can't state that about a product which has dozens of manyears of additional work - it's true that the Java EE API and management are the same.

So you can migrate as-is, and solve problems as they come.

Not sure if this question is still relevant since it's 3 years old, but just for clarification :)